# REST API return child

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a learning student and I am trying to return a piece of data with REST API. However, I just can't get it the way I want it. Below you can see a part of what is happening now.

```
"receipt": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "First item",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Second item",
        },
```

But I want it like the code down below, without the `"receipt": {` first.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First item",
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Second item",
},
```

I can't really figure out how to do it.. I spend 2 days of my life trying to get this.

Below you will see my View and Serializer.

```
class FavoritesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Favorite
    fields = ['receipt']
    depth = 2


class FavoritesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Favorite.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FavoritesSerializer

    def getUser(self):
        queryset = Favorite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        serializer = FavoritesSerializer(queryset, many=True)    
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And my Model.

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    receipt = models.ForeignKey(Receipt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

If someone can help me, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Try removing `fields = ['receipt']` from class `Meta`

Comment: Could you share your model, please?

Comment: @Chris Ive added my Model to the post :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a list of dictionary objects in one response those must be in a list. Like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First item",
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Second item",
}]
```

You can do this to achieve that,

```
class FavoritesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Favorite.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FavoritesSerializer

    def getUser(self):
        queryset = Favorite.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        serializer = FavoritesSerializer(queryset, many=True)    
        return Response(data=serializer.data['recipt'])
```